# Using different method depending on class in Java

Tags: java, class, reflection, methods

I'm trying to reduce some code duplication. Currently i got two methods that are almost identical, the major difference being calling two separate methods within them.

Below is basically what i wanna do:

```
private void combinedMethod(StandardClass sc, MyClass mc)
{
    Method m = null;
    if(mc instanceof MySubClass1)
        m = sc.RelevantFor1();
    if(mc instanceof MySubClass2)
        m = sc.RelevantFor2();

    m(mc.getA(), mc.getB());
}
```

I've tested (and it works) this using reflection. But is there a better way of doing it? I read somewhere that reflection is slow and only to be used as a last resort. Is it in this case?

Also in this case the StandardClass is a standard class in the java api. The Class I send in is of my own making.

Comment: This question is a bit unclear because it muddles up getting "some method" on 'sc' and using instanceof on 'c'. They are two different issues - and reflection is not needed for using a public member of a compile-time accessible nominative type.

Comment: I suggest you to form some better replica of your exact situation. Using `SomeClass`, `Class` and `someMethod()` is really confusing. And show the declaration of `MyClass` and subclasses.

Comment: user123...: c/sc missed in edit, fixed.
Rhohit: Better? I really don't see the point in being more specific than this. What method i wanna call is depending on what subclass to MyClass I pass.

Comment: @apelsin Better than before..

Answer (score 3):

It isn't clear how exactly those methods look like, or what they are doing, but it seems like a perfect polymorphism case. You can create a method in super class - `MyClass` I suppose in this case. And override those methods in your subclasses.

Now, when you call that method on `MyClass` reference, appropriate subclass method will be called based on actual instance. Now invoke whatever method you want to invoke in respective overridden methods.

Somewhere along the lines of:

```
class MyClass {
    public void method(StandardClass sc) { }
}

class MySubClass1 extends MyClass {
    public void method(StandardClass sc) {
        sc.method(getA(), getB());
    }
}

class MySubClass2 extends MyClass {
    public void method(StandardClass sc) {
        sc.anotherMethod(getA(), getB());
    }
}
```

And then your `combinedMethod` looks like:

```
private void combinedMethod(StandardClass sc, MyClass c) {
    c.method(sc);
}
```

Comment: Both methods have the same number of parameters and types. And the methods I wanna use doesn't come from Class or it's subclasses. It's from SomeClass, which in my case is a class from the standard java api.

Comment: @apelsin I understand that. Please look into the example I posted. You should get an idea. I'm still calling method of `SomeClass` only.

Comment: I'm aware of this type of solution. But the StandardClass i'm using doesn't belong being in MyClass or any subclasses of it. The CombinedMethod() is in the View/Gui package, and the MyClass and it's subclasses are in the Models package and are basically just data. I don't feel like it's logical to mix them.

Comment: @apelsin Are you using Java 8? Lambdas might be of help in that case.

Comment: Yes, I've not looked into lambas that much yet, gonna take a quip peek at it.